# Factorio: On/off circuit network

Tags: factorio

I want to create a circuit network that essentially act like a power on/off button that is linked to 10 stack inserter that will take raw material and put them in a rocket silo only when I want them to otherwise it would drain some of my precious resources (mostly blue circuit and steel).

My current setup is that there are ten requester chest, has to be 10 chest otherwise not enough space, that take in 1000 of the 3 critical resources need for a launch.

Also room for thing in my base is at a premium. So nothing too big.

[image: Late-game with rocket silo]

Comment: It's hard to understand what the actual question is here, and your answer might be easier to understand if you added a picture.

Comment: @TimmyJim I meant a picture to his answer. It might be easier to understand what the solution is with a picture of it, not the picture included in the question.

Comment: What do you mean with "only when you want them to"?

Comment: No problem I added a picture for my answer.

Comment: It might help, for people reading this *in the FUTURE!* to make a MCVE of this.

Comment: MCVE? What do you meant by that? Like a blueprint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting all inserter leading to rocket silo to only move thing if the logistic system has 100 or less than space science packs.

It seem to be simpler than trying to use circuit network and has the bonus of saving on space.

Here is how I did it in-game. You have to make sure that all space science pack end up in a logistic chest otherwise it will count as zero even at 30k inside non-logistic chest. Notice my logistic chest is at 200 so inserter are paused until that fall under 100.

[image: Solution]